# How can I create a catch that ensures nothing other than a number is entered into a textbox but also accepts a blank entry

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, try-catch

I have a textbox. The lecturer says I must have a catch to ensure nothing other than a valid number is entered but the textbox is optional. In other words the user might not make an entry at all. I have a catch for it that catches any letters entered but it also catches if the textbox is left blank. In other words it says a valid number must be entered even if it's blank. How can I make a catch that accepts no entry or a number but nothing else?

Here's the relevant part of my code;

```
try
{
    if (decimal.Parse(lessTradeInTextBox.Text) > decimal.Parse(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The trade-in price cannot be greater than the purchase price");
        Keyboard.Focus(lessTradeInTextBox);
    }
    else
    {
        // calculations go here
    }
}
catch (FormatException theException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number for the Trade-in   price. \n" + "Reason: " + theException.Message);

    Keyboard.Focus(lessTradeInTextBox);
    lessTradeInTextBox.SelectAll();
}
catch (Exception theException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error, GeneralTransform Error. " + theException.Message);
    Keyboard.Focus(lessTradeInTextBox);
    lessTradeInTextBox.SelectAll();
}
```

Comment: So at which point you are receiving the error/exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a in-line if statement like this:

```
try
{
    string lessTrade = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lessTradeInTextBox.Text)) ? "0" : lessTradeInTextBox.Text;
    string vehiclePrice = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text)) ? "0" : vehiclePriceTextBox.Text;

    if (decimal.Parse(lessTrade) > decimal.Parse(vehiclePrice))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The trade-in price cannot be greater than the purchase price");
        Keyboard.Focus(lessTradeInTextBox);
    }
    else
    {
        // calculations go here
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //do your exception handling.
}
```

Using a `try-catch` is not a cost-effecient solution. So I suggest the code below:

```
string lessTrade = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lessTradeInTextBox.Text)) ? "0" : lessTradeInTextBox.Text;
string vehiclePrice = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text)) ? "0" : vehiclePriceTextBox.Text;

decimal lessTradeD, vehiclePriceD;
if (decimal.TryParse(lessTrade, out lessTradeD) & decimal.TryParse(vehiclePrice, out vehiclePriceD))
{
    if (lessTradeD > vehiclePriceD)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The trade-in price cannot be greater than the purchase price");
        Keyboard.Focus(lessTradeInTextBox);
    }
    else
    {
        // calculations go here
    }
}
else
{
    //wrong input, do your exceptin handling.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` condition to do the check for an empty string. I.e.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lessTradeInTextBox.Text) &&
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text) &&
(decimal.Parse(lessTradeInTextBox.Text) > decimal.Parse(vehiclePriceTextBox.Text)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `null` check in your code outside the code block relevant to this particular textbox and allow it to bypass everything inside of it and just keep things as it is. Something like this should help you :

```
if(yourTextBox.Text != "")
{
   //your relevant code and all manipulations on that textbox, only if its not null.
}
else
{
    //to do something when textbox.Text is null
}
```

In this way, you allow it to bypass the code if its null and it wont show exception for `null` case.

Hope this helps.